# signalR2: OnDisconnected fires immediately on page refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

Isnt the OnDisconnect method supposed to wait a default 30s before being fired? For me it fires instantly on page refresh(F5).

I have a User object which keeps track of a users connections in a hashset.

In my hub I have a dictionary to keep track of connected users.

OnConnected: I add that user to the dictionary, if the user is already there, I just add another connectionid to the users hashset.

OnDisconnected: I remove that connectionId from the calling users hashset, and if he doesnt have any connections left I remove the user object from the dictionary.

I need to keep track of the user object, and I lose it on every page refresh(F5) cause OnDisconnected gets fired straight away and removes the users only connection and the object. And when the page loads again, a new user object gets created, cause the old one was removed straight away.

My Implementation looks something like this

```
  private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, User> Users 
        = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, User>();

    public override Task OnConnected() {

        string userName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

        var user = Users.GetOrAdd(userName, _ => new User {
            Name = userName,
            ConnectionIds = new HashSet<string>()
        });

        lock (user.ConnectionIds) {

            user.ConnectionIds.Add(connectionId);

            // TODO: Broadcast the connected user
        }

        return base.OnConnected();

        }

        public override Task OnDisconnected() {

        string userName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

        User user;
        Users.TryGetValue(userName, out user);

        if (user != null) {

            lock (user.ConnectionIds) {

                user.ConnectionIds.RemoveWhere(cid => cid.Equals(connectionId));

                if (!user.ConnectionIds.Any()) {

                    User removedUser;
                    Users.TryRemove(userName, out removedUser);

                    // You might want to only broadcast this info if this 
                    // is the last connection of the user and the user actual is 
                    // now disconnected from all connections.
                    Clients.Others.userDisconnected(userName);
                }
            }
        }

        return base.OnDisconnected();
    }
```

Comment: When you refresh the page you're basically leaving the page, causing the disconnect. Why do you think it would "wait" for 30 seconds?

Comment: DisconnectTimeout - Represents the amount of time to wait after a connection goes away before raising the disconnect event. Default is 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this by running a task inside the OnDisconnected method and delaying the method by x Seconds then checking if the user has reconnected, if he hasn't remove him from the list.

```
public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
        {
                Task mytask = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    UserDisconnected(Context.User.Identity.Name, Context.ConnectionId);
                });



            return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
        }


private async void UserDisconnected(string un, string cId)
        {
            await Task.Delay(10000);
            string userName = un;
            string connectionId = cId;

            User user;
            enqueuedDictionary.TryGetValue(userName, out user);

            if (user != null)
            {
                lock (user.ConnectionIds)
                {

                    user.ConnectionIds.RemoveWhere(cid => cid.Equals(connectionId));

                    if (!user.ConnectionIds.Any())
                    {

                        User removedUser;
                        enqueuedDictionary.TryRemove(userName, out removedUser);
                        ChatSession removedChatSession;
                        groupChatSessions.TryRemove(userName, out removedChatSession);
                        UpdateQ(removedUser.QPos);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```